# Tableau Show/Hide dimension comparison

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to create a filter in Tableau that excludes 1 date depending on the time of year.  We look at monthly/quarterly reporting where the current month is always the previous month and so on.  So for example, in January, December would equal the 'Current Month', 'Current Quarter' and November would equal the 'Previous Month'.  8 times a year, there will be a scenario where Current Month = Current Quarter or Current Quarter = Previous Month.  I would like to create a filter that excludes either 'Current Month' or 'Previous Month' whenever they equal the 'current quarter'.

I tried something like this:

```
IF [Period Selection AQ] = "Current Month End" <> [Period Selection AQ] = "Current Quarter End" THEN "Show"
Elseif [Period Selection AQ] = "Previous Month End" <> [Period Selection AQ] = "Current Quarter End" THEN "Show"
ELSE "Hide" end
```

However, this did not work.  Any thoughts on how i can arrange the logic would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a tableau to share?

Comment: Unfortunately not, it’s work related and I cannot share.  I am just trying to understand how to make an if statement like this work in tableau.